# Terminal command that is the same as copy paste in Finder?

Tags: terminal, finder, backup, symlink, rsync

I'm curious. As far as `cp` and `rsync` I see all these different options. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you copy + paste in Finder, lets say from one hard drive to another, it should preserve:

- All file attributes (access time, modified time etc.)
- All Symbolic Links
- Recurse through the directory structure
- (Can't think of anything else to preserve)?

So in the end, when you copy paste in Finder, everything will be **an exact copy**, just located in a different parent directory.

What I'm looking for is a command that mimics exactly what Finder does when you copy + paste. That will answer this question...

If it turns out Finder doesn't do what I think it does please explain, and show the command line equivalents for what Finder *actually* does... it must be calling a command when you use the GUI - right?

Comment: What you need is the ditto command that does exactly the same as copy files in Finder. See man ditto for additional information.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve file attributes, symbolic links, and recursive structure, `rsync` should suffice:

```
rsync -a ~/somefolder /Volumes/SomeUSB/
```

The `-a` (archive) flag is a shortcut for the following `rsync` options:

> `--recursive` recurse into directories
>   `--links` copy symlinks as symlinks
>   `--perms` preserve permissions
>   `--times` preserve times
>   `--group` sets the group of the destination file to be the same as the source file
>   `--owner` sets the owner of the destination file to be the same as the source file (if you're copying to a remote system, the remote SSH user will need to have superuser status for this)
>   `--devices` rsync will transfer character and block device files to the remote system.